# I want to make something expire in thirty days from purchase date

Tags: java, mysql

I am developing a side project and am unsure how to go about this. I am making a product expire 30 days after its purchasing date. I am not too sure what I should use. I was thinking System.currentTimeMillis(), and storing that as the purchase date or even using timestamps but I am not entirely too sure on what to use in my program and SQL table.

Comment: Sounds like a simple date comparison. Where are you facing errors/issues? What is stopping you?

Comment: Are you kind of talking about license expiry for usage of the project?

Comment: So pretty much what I want to achieve is making a product expire 30 days after its purchasing date. I am not too sure what I should use. I was thinking System.currentTimeMillis(), and storing that as the purchase date or even using timestamps but I am not entirely too sure on what to use in my program and SQL table.

Comment: Anything? This is pretty urgent.

Comment: @Vinex_, insert date+30 days in table's column expiry date. When querying, see the current date if > expiry_date to validate it. If need to remove expired products from time to time, need to run a separate batch process to do the clean up of expired data